# Cookies not set properly on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies, mobile

I have a problem with setting cookies on wordpress
here is my code :

```
    function set_cookie_if_not_set() {
    $cookie_value = 'viewed';
    $dpmain = '.eva.guru';
    $extime = time() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60); // 30 days in seconds
        // Check if the cookie is already set
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['lead_magnet_popup'])) {
        // Set the cookie
        setcookie('lead_magnet_popup', $cookie_value, $extime, '/', $dpmain);
    }
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['newsletter_popup'])) {
        // Set the cookie
        $cookie_valueb = 'viewed';
        $domain_set = '.eva.guru';
        $onemonth = time() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60); // 30 days in seconds
        setcookie('newsletter_popup', $cookie_valueb, $onemonth, '/', $domain_set);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'set_cookie_if_not_set');
```

its working perfectly fine on my local but not on server..
on server it works like 10% of the times
because of that I used js cookie

```
    // Check if the cookie is already set
if (document.cookie.indexOf("newsletter_popup") === -1) {
    // Set the cookie expiration date
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)); // 30 days in milliseconds
  
    // Set the cookie
    document.cookie = "newsletter_popup=viewed; expires=" + date.toUTCString() + "; path=/";
}
```

and it's working completely fine on desktop but again I have problem with mobile device and it doesn't work on mobile

btw as I checked plugins cookie works fine for example I have GDPR plugin and as I checked its cookie, it was completely fine on mobile and desktop